# Shirt thread intertwined with tzitzah

Tags: halacha, clothing, tzitzis

If part of a shirt thread became entangled with a tzitzah (tzitzis fringe), and you can't get it untangled, is it still valid as a tzitzah?

Comment: @Isaac is it really a singular word? ציצת נובל צבי תפארתו certainly seems like it's non-construct form would be ציצה

Comment: It should be fine...are you asking because it might be an extra thread?

Comment: @chachamNisan i'm asking because i thought it might invalidate the tzitzah that it is intertwined with.

Comment: @DoubleAA I see now that *tziztah* is used in this sense in the *Kitzur*, but I maintain that replacing it with "tzitzis fringe" is an improvement in this general-interest tziztzis question, from a jargon-accessibility point of view.